# How do I update the value of a date field across every cell in the database table in MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a “dateExpiry” field in a set of database tables that I would like to programmatically change to the same date. Some cells are blank, others have dates in them. I would like them all to have the same date, e.g. 2016-12-30

Can anybody assist with this code?

Comment: Can I use:

UPDATE table_name SET dateExpiry = 2016-12-30

or is this a mysql command?

Comment: Depends on the data type of your `dateExpiry` column.

Comment: Can you show us the table/column definition?

Comment: @RobertGodino yes, that would work. Keep in mind this might also over write existing, valid dates. So if there's a criteria you have to use to retain certain dates, you have to use a `WHERE` clause in the statement

Comment: A little trickier than I thought. The element or value I need to change is within a larger table cell string.

So, I need to change the <lastLogin> value only that sits in the in the cell "Xml" of the table "dbo.cmsContentXml".

My other question is where do I actually input that query? I’m new to MSSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know table names you can do simple update, John's answer is much more complex. This is very basic solution:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET dateExpiry = '2016-12-30'
```

If you are not sure about tables names, you can find them with below query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'dateExpiry'
```

As question become more specific (xml) below you can find something helpfull:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET XMLColumn.modify('
  replace value of (/Root/XMLnodeElement/text())[1]
  with "new value"
')
WHERE yourCondition
```

To check if your element exists in XML:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE XMLColumn.exist('/Root/XMLnodeElement') = 1
```

**EDIT:**
Based on last comment, please have a look on below code, you need to provide full path to lastLogin node.

```
UPDATE cmsContentXml
SET xml.modify('
  replace value of (/node/anotherSubnode/anotherSubnode/lastLogin/text())[1]
  with "2/25/2017"
')
WHERE xml LIKE '<node%'
```

Comment: Hi Pawel, this is now a little trickier than I thought. The element or value I need to change is within a larger table cell string. So, I need to change the <**lastLogin**> value only that sits in the in the cell "**Xml**" of the table "**dbo.cmsContentXml**". My other question is where do I actually input that query? I’m new to MSSQL.

Comment: to provide more specific answer I need XML sample with all nodes, but my edited answer should point you to right direction. I have tested this on my db.

Comment: Hi Pawel, we used the following code and it changed the values for the parameters/fields that are blank. Eg. <lastLogin></lastLogin> is a blank field, so it’s being updated. However where it contains an old date, it’s not being changed.

Can we revise this script so it amends the contents of <lastLogin></lastLogin> no matter what’s inside – whether it’s blank or populated with an old date?
`UPDATE cmsContentXml
SET xml = 
 cast(REPLACE(cast(xml as nvarchar(max)), '<lastLogin></lastLogin>', '<lastLogin>2/25/2017</lastLogin>') as ntext)
WHERE xml LIKE '<node%'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use DYNAMIC SQL for this

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''

Select @SQL = ';Update '+QUOTENAME(Table_Schema)+'.'+QUOTENAME(Table_Name)+' Set [dateExpiry]=''2016-12-30'''+char(13)
 From  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME = 'dateExpiry'
--Exec(@SQL)  
Select @SQL
```

If Satisfied with the Generated SQL, remove the comments before Exec()

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the good work already spoken by others here, the column seems to not be the XML datatype, but could be NVARCHAR(...) or even NTEXT. Therefore, will most probably need to loop through the table and modify the xml, and then update the record again.

Perhaps something like that coded below.  This will update all last login dates to 31st December 2099, by casting it to the XML datatype first, modifying it, then pushing it back into the table.  This also assumes some Primary Key or Identifying record in the table, here named the "Id" column:

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (Id INT, XmlText NTEXT)
INSERT INTO @TEMP (Id, XmlText)
SELECT Id, xml
FROM YourTable
WHERE xml LIKE '<node%'


DECLARE @Id INT
DECLARE @Xml XML
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TEMP)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @Id = Id FROM @TEMP
    SELECT @Xml = CAST(xml AS XML) FROM YourTable WHERE Id = @Id


    SET @Xml.modify('replace value of (/node/lastLogin/text())[1] with "2099-12-31"')  -- Might need to change the xml path to exact path in xml

    UPDATE YourTable
    SET xml = CAST(@Xml AS NVARCHAR(MAX))   -- Assuming NVARCHAR(MAX).  If NTEXT, will require another cast back to NTEXT.
    WHERE Id = @Id


    DELETE FROM @TEMP WHERE Id = @Id
END
```

Comment: That’s perfect Stefan. That worked exactly as I needed. I believe I failed to mention in my question that the data was being written to XML, so thanks for exploring that angle... and a big thanks to John and Pawel for steering a course through this problem.